# c++ read file in network byte order

Tags: c++, file, networking, byte

I'm trying to read a file in c++ in network byte order format.

so far I tried with (just to read the first integer (2bytes)):

```
ifstream in ("input.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);
unsigned short x;
in >> x;
```

and some other solutions I found online.
None seems to be working.

Thak you in advance,

Comment: Check the `ntohs()` and `ntohl()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

`in >> x` makes little sense if you're slurping this as binary data. `operator >>` is for *formatted* extraction. You should likely be using the [`std::istream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) method and following it with `ntohs()`

Something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <netinet/in.h>

ifstream in ("input.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);
uint16_t x;

if (in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x)))
{
    x = ntohs(x);

    // use x here
}
```

... assuming your file is raw binary. Note also the change to type. That entry being read better be 16 bits wide for any platform independence, and the writer should be aware of this as well.

Comment: @magodiez do you you mean the equivalent bit-type ? I.e. `int8_t` or `uint8_t` ? If you mean what is the equivalent function of `ntohs`, there is none. Those function address the issue of endian-independence, and single-byte values don't apply.